# What do the operators bigvee and bigwedge mean in modal logic? Eg, $\bigvee_{\delta_C\in\Delta_C}\langle\delta_C\rangle\top$

Tags: logic, notation, modal-logic

What do the operators $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ mean in modal logic? For example I recently saw the following "statement"
$$\bigvee_{\delta_C\in\Delta_C}\langle\delta_C\rangle\top$$

Which has a description saying "(Active)". Even though this might seems meaningless without knowledge of what the notation means. Could someone please answer what such notation $\bigvee$ would try to convey? Same with $\bigwedge$?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, in mathematics,

$$
{\Large R}_{\omega\in\Omega}x_\omega,
$$

for any (typically associative) binary operation $R$ and (ordered) set $\Omega$, with variables $x_i$, means repeated application of $R$ to the $x_i$ (in the order specified by $\Omega$); for example,

$$\bigvee_{i\in\{1,2, 3\}}a_i=a_1\vee a_2\vee a_3.$$

Answer (score 1):

The same way $\sum$ and $\prod$ denote repeated addition and multiplication, $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ denote, respectively, logical OR and AND repeated over the elements described.

Eg.
$$\bigvee_{i=1}^5 A_i \Leftrightarrow A_1\vee A_2\vee A_3\vee A_4\vee A_5$$